# unable to calculate time complexity of below algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I stuck at a problem ,It was a basically implementation problem ,It passed all the test cases But I have doubt regarding its time complexity.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1e6 + 100; i++) {
    sort(v[i].begin(), v[i].end());
}
```

The time complexity of this loop seems to be O(n*n*logn) .Then It should definitely fail because n value can be 10^6.Even O(n*n) fail  for such higher 
value of n,I have seen already so many times on codeforces.

What is its correct time complexity??

[Problem link](http://codeforces.com/contest/558/problem/B)

Please forgive me if it is too basic!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
const int N = 1e6 + 100;
vector<int> a, f(1e6 + 100);
vector<int>v[N];
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    a.resize(n);
    int mx = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        f[a[i]]++;
        v[a[i]].push_back(i);
        mx = max(mx, f[a[i]]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1e6 + 100; i++) {
        sort(v[i].begin(), v[i].end());
    }
    int diff = INT_MAX;
    int ans[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1e6 + 100; i++) {
        if (f[i] == mx) {
            int temp = v[i][v[i].size() - 1] - v[i][0];
            if (diff > temp) {
                diff = temp;
                ans[0] = v[i][0];
                ans[1] = v[i][v[i].size() - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << ans[0] + 1 << " " << ans[1] + 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v` is an array of vectors. The *total* size of all those vectors is `n`: every element of `a` corresponds to some element in some vector in `v`. One of the vectors might have length `n` itself, but then all the others must be empty. They cannot all be large.

So the time complexity of sorting all those vectors is in O(n log n) as well. "As well" because it is in O(n² log n) too, that's just a more loose bound.